# Django 1.7 - Any way to stream mp3 playlists?

Tags: django, html, stream, mp3, playlist

I am using django 1.7.5 on python 2.7 and I was wondering if there was a solution for streaming mp3 files? Preferably a stream player with an html5 fallback for non-flash devices.

I'm asking because I am having trouble finding something relevant that isn't over 3 years old and outdated to my version of django. I am open to any and all suggestions. I don't necessarily need a hand-holding solution but a nudge in the right direction would be REALLY appreciated!

EDIT: I did find this but I am not sure if I can implement it: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create playlists dynamically? Because if it's a static file (a mp3 or playlist file, etc) you basically do not need Django at all. A web server like nginx or Apache can serve the file directly to your javascript/HTML5 player. Or you put it in your static files or media folder if you use runserver.

If you want to create a mp3 playlist for your frontend player with django, checkout this tutorial:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter13.html

Comment: Okay yeah maybe I should have worded things differently. I don't need to play .m3u or .pls files. I would like to use maybe a shortcode (or a bit of script) within blog posts to display a player. So for example if I used [streamplayer="song1.mp3,song2.mp3,song3.mp3,song4.mp3,song5.mp3"] it would generate a stream player box with controls and a scrollable playlist (that would all be handled with css obviously) within the blog post.

Comment: IT DOESNT have to be a shortcode, that was just an example of how I would like to be able to implement the stream player within my posts. I had a feeling I would have to use some outside scripts to take care of it (like soundmanager2) but I am still not sure it would do the job.

Comment: You could do that with a template snippet which would also need to hold all dependencies (JS files etc) see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include  You can pass arguments to it (a list for example). Or create your own template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters.

Comment: Okay thank you, sounds great! I will get on trying this stuff with soundmanager2, and see if I can get something to stream.